# Automatically refresh span text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a span element like this:

```
  <span id="test" name="testing" >Test </span>
```

The text of span i.e Test might change based on other operations in the page.
I want to automatically refresh the span text say after 2 seconds.
How can I achieve this using jquery?
Please help.

Comment: Refresh it from what data source?

Comment: Do you want continuous refreshing or 2 seconds after the pages loads? Can you add your HTML and any jQuery you've tried?

Comment: I am using the following for testing: setInterval(function(){ $('#test').html('hello');  },2000);

Comment: How to reload it with same value ?

Comment: Ok, first I would like to know how to just refresh its original value every 2 secs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the javascript setInterval to create a timer like effect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Code will be something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#test').text('newtext');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. if you want to repeat it once, use the former, if you want to refresh continually after a span of 2 seconds, use the latter:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#test").text("text from other operations"); },2000);
```

or

```
setInterval(function() { $("#test").text("text from other operations"); },2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = setInterval(dostuff, 2000);

function dostuff() {
    /* do stuff */
    $('span#test').html('some stuff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateSpan(){
  var newText;
  // Compute new text here
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=newTest;
}
setInterval("updateSpan()",2000);
```

This even works without jQuery.